# How to resolve parse error in Splint

Tags: parsing, splint

Splint is not continuing it's checking after finding parse errors. I've tried with +trytorecover option also but no change.

Please let me know on how to use +trytorecover to make Splint attempt to continue after a parse error.

Here is what I'm receiving,

```
161: splint +trytorecover spy.c
Splint 3.1.1 --- 19 Jul 2006

spy.c:41:12: Parse Error: Non-function declaration: byte_4 :
                int. Attempting to continue.
spy.c:41:12: Cannot recover from parse error.
*** Cannot continue.
```